# Delete all lines that have no value

Tags: sed

I need to remove variables that have no value with a sed command.

Input:

```
a: x sdvsv rhrh
b: 
c: sdbbb
d:
```

Output:

```
a: x sdvsv rhrh
c: sdbbb
```

Comment: Why would you attempt to match the beginning of the line in the middle of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '/:\s*$/d'
```

works **for your example**.

more general way:

```
sed '/^[^:]\+:\s*$/d'
```

Comment: I didn't know of `\s` shortcut to mean whitespace in `sed`. Good to know, **+1**

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NF>1' inputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '/^[^:]*:\s*$/d' a.txt
```

Match all characters followed by a '**:**', followed by any number of spaces, and the end of line.

Comment: works for the example text. however if a non-empty value ending with `:`, your command will remove that entry too. e.g. `c: sdbbb:`

Answer (score 0):

`sed -E '/^\w+:\s*$/d'`

match any line composed of a non empty word followed by a colon and any spaces, and deletes it.